# What does "blinker down" mean?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I read a comment written by Participant X who was asked to be more respectful in criticizing someone's question on SE.  X wrote

> I'm truly sorry but I can't blinker myself that far down.

What does that mean?  Where does the meaning you know (if any) come from?

I looked at thefreedictionary.com which covers multiple dictionaries, and I checked urbandictionary as well.  I didn't come up with the slightest clue.

If there is more research I should do and show, please let me know.

If this word means nothing to anybody, then I'll conclude he just made it up and it's part of his personal repertoire of coined words that no one beyond his immediate circle understands.

Comment: I think you are thinking of the alternative expression 'bunker up/down'. The [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blinker+up%2C+blinker+down%2C+bunker+up%2C+bunker+down&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbunker%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbunker%20down%3B%2Cc0) gives no results for 'blinker up/down' but does return a response for 'bunker up/down'.

Comment: @NigelJ - I'm not the person who wrote it!  Do you mean that the person who wrote it might have been thinking of *bunker down*?  But at any rate, from what I know of *bunker down*, it doesn't make sense with his sentence.

Answer (score 3):

to **blinker**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/blinker)

> to put blinkers on; to obscure with or as if with blinkers;  Having or showing a narrow or limited outlook or point of view.
>   ‘a blinkered attitude’

"I'm truly sorry **but I can't blinker myself that far down**"

Meaning:

I cannot ignore, blind myself to this fact, be so myopic, ignore,  look away and/or down.

Etymology: in the figurative sense, 1849, from horses wearing blinkers to limit the range of their vision (see blinker).  [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/blinkered)

Comment: Thanks.  Can you talk about the "down" part?  Was that just creativity on his part, or is it a thing?

Comment: One definition of "down" is 2.
to or at a lower level of intensity, volume, or activity.
"keep the noise down".  ( via Google)

Comment: What exactly is “Ver” supposed to mean in the last line? (Note that while _blinker_ is indeed the present tense of the Danish verb _blinke_, the English verb _blinker_ is derived from the noun _blinker_, which is quite regularly formed within English from the verb _to blink_. The Danish verb is cognate with the English one, but it is not its etymological origin.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet my mistake ... edited

Comment: i edited...  and @xanne added a good comment

Comment: I still don't understand why "down" would be added, and how the meaning would be changed.

Comment: down: to a finer or more concentrated state. He could not re-fine or 'blinker down' his comment any further. In effect he stood by it.